# GUI Grid in Java

Tags: java, object, user-interface, grid

I need to evenly space objects given a certain graphics context and a 2d array of objects. I'm having trouble trying to create algorithm that will do this for me. I can access the width and height of the graphics context and 2d array, and have "space" objects at my disposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want any border or gaps between objects, the height and width of the objects should be (width / space) and (height / space) (make sure you use double or float for the division) and then you use:

```
for(int i=0;i<space;i+=objectheight)
    for(int j=0;j<space;j+=objectwidth)
        drawobject(j,i,objectwidth,objectheight);
```

If the objects are fixed in size I assume you want to 'center' them, then only the drawcall changes to:

```
drawobject(j + (( objectwidth - object.getWidth() ) / 2 ), i + (( objectheight - object.getHeight() ) / 2));
```

Where objectwidth is still the previously mentioned (width / space)

Comment: I do want them to take up the space of the entire graphics context though, so I will need gaps.